# Should you leave the Laravel debug bar on a published site?

Tags: php, laravel

New to using Laravel and php.  I'm working on a project, and there's a debug bar on the bottom of a published web app.

Is this standard? Or should I tell my manager to remove it?  Is there any security issues?

.env is currently:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Comment: **DO NOT LEAVE DEBUG MODE ON IN AN APP THAT IS ON THE INTERNET EVER**

Comment: I'm sorry but once did not feel enough to point this out. **DO NOT LEAVE DEBUG MODE ON IN AN APP THAT IS ON THE INTERNET EVER**

Comment: I'm sorry but twice did not feel enough to point this out. **DO NOT LEAVE DEBUG MODE ON IN AN APP THAT IS ON THE INTERNET EVER**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is a security concern.**

The debug bar should only be available to the developer(s) during development and never exposed to users on the Internet.

In a production environment, the `APP_DEBUG` property should be set to `false`.

Per Laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#debug-mode

> For local development, you should set the APP_DEBUG environment
> variable to true. In your production environment, this value should
> always be false. If the variable is set to true in production, you
> risk exposing sensitive configuration values to your application's end
> users.